# postfix - unknown group: vmail

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot

I have a VPS running `Debian 8` in which I used [this tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/perfect-server-debian-8-jessie-apache-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3/) to set up. It is running `dovecot` and `postfix`. Recently I have started receiving errors every few minutes in my `mail.err` log file which look like this:

```
postfix/pipe[4274]: fatal: get_service_attr: unknown group: vmail
```

Additionally, mail will not receive or send. It is all being backed up in the queue.

I have no idea where to go from here. I have checked that both the `vmail` user and group exist and have no conflicting IDs, I have even removed them and re-added them, but I cannot find out what is causing this error. I have tried re-installing postfix and dovecot with no success, and Google was of no help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that `/etc/group` was not world readable. I must have accidentally overwritten the permissions somehow. I used `chmod 644` on `/etc/group` and `/etc/passwd` and that fixed it :)

[Here's a more detailed article.](https://medium.com/mitchtalmadge/a-solution-to-postfixs-unknown-group-vmail-error-de5f4885d1ee)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, for me it was that the `vmail` user and group had not been created properly.

The script I followed to setup dovecot and postfix lacked the line where it was created and the info that it needs to be created with UID 5000 and GID 5000.

After creating the group and the user and rebooting the system worked fine.